# Have dynamic content span across pages in php

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I have the following code that dynamically loads items in an invoice.  I am looking for a way to adds excess items to a new page, and so on.  I would like to limit the # of items on a page to a set amount, say 15 items.  Is there a way to do this in php?  The code below is within a document that uses dompdf to appear in pages form

```
foreach ( $invoice['InvoiceDetail'] as $key=>$item){
        $html .= '<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; line-height: 15px;">';
            $itemNo = isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id'] : '';
            $itemName = isset($item['productName']) ? $item['productName']: '';
            $price = isset($item['price']) ? invoiceNumFormat($item['price']): '';
            $quantity = isset($item['quantity']) ? $item['quantity'] : '';
            $total = invoiceNumFormat( $item['price']*$item['quantity']);

            $html .= '<td style="text-align: left"><h5>'.$itemNo.'</h5></td>';
            $html .= '<td style="text-align: left">'.$itemName.'</td>';
            $html .= '<td style="text-align: left">'.$price.'</td>';
            $html .= '<td style="text-align: left" width="10px">'.$quantity.'</td>';
            $html .= '<td style="text-align: right">'.$total.'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
```

[image: Dynamic Example]

Comment: What's the nature of "dynamically loads"?  The traditional/canonical method for a database query is a LIMIT clause, with a per-page count and the LIMIT for the 2nd page determined by a little math (( $pagenumber - 1) * $num_per_page) ...

Comment: @Zaki that api shows me how to load an element from an external source.  The content I have is generated on the fly - I just need to figure out how to segregate it.

Comment: @Kkinsey I thought LIMIT actually limited the results, example LIMIT 20, would limit 20 results even if there were 100.  Even if it worked in a way that you could say "limit 15 per page", how would I segregate the pages in between a header / footer, AND beginning page, end page?

Comment: LIMIT can take two parameters.  LIMIT 0, 20 = first twenty results.  LIMIT 20, 20 = next twenty, LIMIT 40,20 , etc.

Comment: @Kkinsey ok, that would work perfect if I would call them exclusively, so right now I have everything in a for each statement... how would I assign the LIMIT command in this instance?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you can generate dynamically and show on page with "LIMIT" in query based on post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular situation you could just indicate to dompdf to break the page, something along the lines of:

```
$itemCount = 0;
foreach ( $invoice['InvoiceDetail'] as $key=>$item){
    $itemCount++;
    $html .= '<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; line-height: 15px;">';

        /* snip */

        if ($itemCount % 20 == 0) {
            $html .= '<tr><td><div style="page-break-before: always;"></div></td></tr>';
        }

        $html .= '<td style="text-align: left"><h5>'.$itemNo.'</h5></td>';
        $html .= '<td style="text-align: left">'.$itemName.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td style="text-align: left">'.$price.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td style="text-align: left" width="10px">'.$quantity.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td style="text-align: right">'.$total.'</td>';

    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Dompdf does not yet recognize page break styling on table rows/cells. Otherwise it would make more sense to place the styling there.

Comment: so where your "/* snip */" is I would insert the header?  would that duplicate the header every time the page breaks?

Comment: `/* snip */` is where I removed your code setting up the table variables. If you're talking about an actual table header just place that in a THEAD element above the TBODY element. If you're talking about a page header use fixed-position elements.

Comment: ha ha ... sorry, I messed up the ternary code. That first `:` is supposed to be a `?`. Fixed.

Comment: that works perfect with the exception of a weird table break - it kills the line total column, and deletes the 5th item off of the table :D

Comment: That is weird, it may have to do with the structure of the table. I tested with a simplified table, I'll see if I can duplicate the issue.

Comment: I haven't. I mean, I tried another simplified example but didn't notice any problems. If you can post a more complete, fully-formed HTML example we can take a closer look. Otherwise you might consider just having the whole thing be an interstitial row instead, though it does add a bit of extra spacing to the top of the second page. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
<?php

$per_page = 20;

if ( $pagenum < 2 || !$pagenum ) {
    $limit_start = 0;
} else {
    $limit_start = (( $pagenum -1 ) * $per_page);
}

$sql = "select foo, bar, baz from table where $conditions limit $limit_start, $per_page";
$db->query( $sql ); //or whatever your method is

// while statement to get data into $invoice array

//foreach statement to display it

//pagination links
```

Comment: I dont want pagination, I want the items past 20 to go on another page that is generated by dompdf, with another header and footer per, so header>1-20 items>footer, header>21-41 items>footer, header>etc etc