# How to limit per page in DomPDF

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, dompdf

Can anyone help in dompdf? I am just newbie to this pdf converter. I am stock on this limiting 19 per page on dompdf.

I tried this code but seems not working
[Have dynamic content span across pages in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093752/have-dynamic-content-span-across-pages-in-php)

```
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $name = $current_user->user_firstname;

    $body ='<div class="header">$name</div>';
    $body .='<div id="content" style="page-break-after:always;"><table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="soa-css">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><strong>Ref No.</strong></td>
    <td align="center" width="25%"><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><strong>Debit</strong></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><strong>Credit</strong></td>
    <td align="center" width="15%"><strong>Balance</strong></td>
  </tr>';
    $trans = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE number = '$number' ORDER by dates");
     $itemCount = 0;
     foreach ( $trans as $tran ) {
      $itemCount++;     
      $body .= '<tr>';
      if ($itemCount % 20 == 0) {
        $body .= '<tr><td><div style="page-break-before: always;"></div></td></tr>';
    }
   $body .='<td>'.$tran->dates.'</td>
    <td>'.$tran->ref.'</td>
    <td>'.$tran->desc.'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$tran->debit.'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$tran->credit.'</td>
    <td align="right">'.$tran->amt.'</td>
  </tr>';
}
</table></div>
```

It seems stop displaying after 19 items on page 1. And the table break.

BTW i want to achieve that it will display 19 items per page. If transaction reach 19 lines in page 1 it will now create 2nd pdf page for the remaining items.

I hope anyone could advice.

Comment: okay so how i am going to display it 19 items per page?

Comment: i want to display the 19 items per page. example in page 1 if the transactions is reach 19 items it will create new page so on and so forth.

Comment: 19 only it stops to that then the page 2 is just blank with header name. If i remove that condition it display all but the records a miss. Let me show you.

Comment: try code of this link:- https://eval.in/876873  (don't see output just use code only)

Comment: weird the pages become x3..example only 3 page suppose to be it become 6 now..hahaha..so weird

Comment: i mean the records should be only 3 pages but after i put your code it mulitiples it.

Comment: not correct cause it creates extra pages..anyways i remove it and back to my original code but i am having issues with this at the last record. Pls check https://imgur.com/a/PxfN6

Comment: Try to use this one:- https://eval.in/876907

Comment: not working maybe i should use for loop?

Comment: this one:- https://eval.in/876920  (i am unable to help-out after this)